# wso2 carbon registry path "/_system" - should I ever need to add/edit items?

Tags: wso2

Is it a correct assumption to assume that the "/_system" registry path and descendants should not be touched by manually editing?

I'm guessing the only time I would need to add something here would be if I was creating a new WSO2 product, and then I would only manage the registry for this new product through code using the `org.wso2.carbon.registry.api` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by manual editing you mean to use the registry resource browser to add remove resources and collections i don't believe there is any thing like "should not be touched" because otherwise the options that are provided in the resource browser will be for nothing. it is possible to add or remove resources.